# C++ Programming: Navigating to user files to save my application data for each user

Tags: c++, windows, directory, subdirectory

I'm trying to access the C:\Users\...

However, each computer has a different user name. I know there is a way to navigate via code to do this, but I can't for the life of me find an answer to this specific problem.

What should I place in ?

Comment: Could you please explain what are you trying to do it bit in more detail? Each computer can have many profiles/users also complicated by corporate networks/groups, etc.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I get the application data path in Windows using C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2899013/how-do-i-get-the-application-data-path-in-windows-using-c)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Windows: How to canonicalize a file to the special folder?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3181120/windows-how-to-canonicalize-a-file-to-the-special-folder)

Answer (score 1):

Windows has a feature called specal folder names. For example you can use `%windir%` to locate the windows directory. As I see you need the `%USERPROFILE%`. You can find more about this, at [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_folder).